# Identification of power connector

Tags: power-supply, connector

What kind of 4-pin power connector is this, displayed in this (exemplary) image? Are there any specs of the maximum current and voltage it is designed to provide?
(Unfortunately this was the best image I could find.)

[image]

Comment: Glad we know it's a Bosch even though the connector is out of focus. -_-  Can you please focus on the connector and re-upload? That's maybe a variant of a [DIN connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector), though the barrel is not exactly round.

Comment: Might be [mini-DIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DIN_connector), or [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_connector#Kycon). You have to measure yourself.

Comment: @try-catch-finally I currently do not have anything with this connector, I was just looking for an image online. But you're right, it is a mini-DIN! Consider adding this as an answer!

Comment: @CL. Thanks, it is indeed a mini-DIN! Please add this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I'm not 100% confident its a DIN connector; its hard to seed because it's blurry, but there's that bulge on the bottom side of the barrel - that won't fit properly into a DIN socket. It might be a proprietary variant though. @CL, fyi

Comment: Well, the data shown on it looks like 5V and 500mA (possibly 15V.. but don't think so) and it is manufactured for the Swiss market  (perhaps others - not sure) looking at the style of the mains prongs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a 4-pin [mini-DIN connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DIN_connector).

Electrically, the connector itself is usually the least sensitive part of a supply. However, mini-DIN is designed to save space, so you can easily run into its limits.

The actual specs depend on the model; you always have to the check the datasheet.
(For example, the CUI MD-40 is rated for 1 A at 100 V, or 2 A at 12 V.)